# Overriding method which is in a static inner class

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to achieve is to override this method:

> public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)

The method is in the SearchView.SearchAutoComplete class 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#SearchView.onCloseClicked%28%29

I know how to extend the SearchView class:

```
public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView {
public CustomSearchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

}
```

But is it possible to extend the inner static class and override the method?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting tons of errors, since some methods are private, then I tried to cut these methods, but it didn't work. I'm asking because I don't know in theory how this works with the static inner classes.

Comment: Isn't onKeyPreIme a method in View? why you can't just Override it if you are extending SearchView?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what are you asking me. I tried overriding this method in the CustomSearchView, but it didn't work.

Comment: btw what do yo need rhis onKeyPreIme for?

Comment: This method clears the focus of the searchView if I hide the keyboard with the backButton. I don't want to clear the focus of the searchView, since I'm showing suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onKeyPreIme](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#1698) method located in SearchAutoComplete class.

Actually you could set your own implementation of this class which implements [TintAutoCompleteTextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintAutoCompleteTextView.java#TintAutoCompleteTextView) but you can't do that.

```
private final SearchAutoComplete mQueryTextView;
```

Modificator `final` of field means that is not accessible through via reflection.

Comment: private doesn't matter ... the final does ...and you can change it by stylling the searchview ... `<item name="layout">@layout/my_searchview_layout</item>` and putting there `id/search_src_text` which should be class the extends `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete`

Comment: @Selvin you can not access to private variable.

Comment: via reflection? yes, you can ... Field.setAccessible(true)

Comment: Can you please provide me an example if it is possible?

Comment: @RadoslavYordanov what the example?

Comment: I was talking about the @Selvin answer.

Comment: @RadoslavYordanov read again attentively. He said : `...the final does...`
So,  any changes to you.